# Using Activator.CreateInstance in generic class combined with "new" modifier on method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, activator

I have a class (DerivedClass) which inherits from BaseClass.
In DerivedClass I use the "new" modifier on a method (SayHello()) since I want to alter the signature - I want to add a return value.
I also have a generic class. The type supplied to the generic class should be of type "BaseClass" (in my case either BaseClass or DerivedClass).

If I use Activator.CreateInstance<T>() to get a new instance of my generic type and then call my method then the method on BaseClass is always called. Why doesn't the SayHello-method on DerivedClass get called when it is set as the generic type?

I made a simple console application to illustrate:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var gc = new GenericClass<DerivedClass>();
            gc.Run();
        }
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        new public int SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello returning int!");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class GenericClass<T> where T : BaseClass
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            var bc = new BaseClass();
            bc.SayHello(); // Hello!

            var dc = new DerivedClass();
            dc.SayHello(); // Hello returning int!

            var dc2 = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            dc2.SayHello(); // Hello!
            Console.WriteLine(dc2.GetType()); // TestApp.DerivedClass

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the combination of:

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T : BaseClass
```

And:

```
new public int SayHello()
```

Tells the compiler, that at compile time, `T` would be of type `BaseClass`, and the method overload matching happens at compile time, not at runtime. Hence, the fact that your run-time type is different, doesn't actually come into play here as it was "ran over" using the `new` modifier, and not via overriding of a virtual method dispatch, as it would if the return type of both your method calls was the same (`void`).

You see it in the generated IL:

**GenericClass`1.Run:**

```
IL_001B:  call        01 00 00 2B 
IL_0020:  stloc.2     // dc2
IL_0021:  ldloca.s    02 // dc2
IL_0023:  constrained. 02 00 00 1B 
IL_0029:  callvirt    UserQuery+BaseClass.SayHello
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't override the method, you're shadowing it.  If you made the method virtual, and override it instead, then you'd get the results you're expecting.

The `Run` method of `GenericClass` doesn't know the runtime type of the object, it only knows that it's a type derived from `BaseClass`, and so it can only bind the implementation of the method in `BaseClass` at compile time.  Since you haven't enabled virtual dispatch through making the method `virtual`, there's no way for it to know about the derived type's method.

Comment: Since I'm changing the signature of the method I can't use override (right?).

Comment: @Björn Yes, you would need to keep the signature the same to override it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic keyword :

```
 dynamic dc2 = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```